Spring Boot 3.0 Multi Module project not access properties file in another my project
I have a problem.
Lets ı explain my project structure and problems.
1. Multi Module Project
you will see project structure below.

auth-service
auth-service-app
auth-service-bom
auth-service-data

Depends on data-core-project


auth-service-service
auth-service-grpc

Github: https://github.com/CihanGurkan01/auth-service
2. Data Core Project
Normal spring boot project. I thought use multi dataSource with SpringJpa repository.
Github: https://github.com/CihanGurkan01/data-core-project
Problem:
I have a properties file it name is data-core-application.yaml in data-core-project. I thought use this properties file in CommonDataSourceProperties.class of data-core-project but ı tryed start multi module project. It is crash because it doesn't see data-core-application.yaml
How Can I See data-core-application.yaml file for multi-project?
enter image description here
When AuthService is starting but it has problem. Because İt doest see properties file of another project resources.

The thing I don't see in your project - is how do you import your beans from   library to auth-service.
Official Spring documentation suggests two different ways of importing a library into your application. One of them is using auto-configuration and the other one is using custom annotations.
I added link of guide how to use auto-configurations.
Here is example how to use Custom Annotations
1) Create annotation + add import configuration classes
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Import(CustomDatasourceConfiguration.class)
public @interface EnableCustomDataSources {
}

2) Deploy and add library to POM
3) Import Annotation to base project
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableFeignClients
@EnableCustomDataSources
public class AuthApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AuthApplication.class, args);
    }

}


3rd variant - the most crunchy I don't recommend using it, I recommend making separate annotation for this at least. But u can test it just to make sure it works.
Add this into your auth-service-app


Hello, Actually ı checked my friends below url. you can see those projects. Can you check urls
https://github.com/CihanGurkan01/auth-service
https://github.com/CihanGurkan01/data-core-project

yes, I checked urls, u have data-core-project which is imported into auth-service-data, which is correct.
But data-core-project does not have neither auto-configuration nor custom annotations that will import configurations to it.  which means that 0 beans will be created on importing it to another project

check this url. This is very very close to your case
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-custom-auto-configuration

Or the 3rd variant, the most crunchy. I will write example in few minutes

I will look into the solution you sent. I hope it solves the problem.Thanks your reply.

I edited my answer, you can test 3rd variant just to make sure it works but still - I don't recommend using it as a production solution)

Yeah ı saw but not working still ı had a null pointer.
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.cihangurkan.datacoreproject.configuration.CommonDataSourceProperties$Hikari.getMinimumIdleLimit()" because the return value of "com.cihangurkan.datacoreproject.configuration.CommonDataSourceProperties.getHikari()" is null
at com.cihangurkan.datacoreproject.util.ConfigurationUtil.checkMinimumIdle(ConfigurationUtil.java:35) ~[data-core-project-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]

At least now it tries to create beans )
that is strange( just to check.
Try to remove / from @PropertySource("classpath:/data-core-application.yaml")

and also - try to move it from yaml to default .properties file.
I researched my older projects I used some crunches to make yaml work in libraries.
Maybe they fixed this in newer versions of spring, but still. try to make it plain properties file

I even see some threads on stackoverflow on topic of how to make yaml work in libraries)

Hi Vadim, thanks your answer. We achive this problem. We committed current code.
